# Latching circuit with ATtiny85

Tags: mosfet, attiny

I would like to know if this circuit will work if i power up  an Arduino (via PWR)[image]

I am suign this circuit as latching circuit and i do not know how to simulate it since i am new to electronics. Thanks in advance.

Comment: by the way, the input voltage Vin = 5V

Comment: Could you explain further what you are trying to do?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy When BS(Button SIgnal) is High then i activate The pin "Load" then power up an Arduino via "PWR".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a latching circuit, as it seems like you are going to "latch" the Load pin in software on Attiny85.

As BSS84 are really a small transistor with very low gate charge, you don't really need a BJT to control it. You can directly drive it from ATTiny85, just invert your software logic and you'll be fine.

And make sure that your Arduino won't consume more than 130mA what BSS84 can handle (or pick another MOSFET with higher allowed current).

PS: I'm not sure what's BEMFA pin are for, but probably a better design would be to use a sleep mode of Arduino when it's not needed and wake it up from interrupt. If you can move the BEMFA pin to it, you can avoid having extra MCU & other parts that way.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, i would like to know if you can suggest me any other MOSFET that can handle more current.
I wanted to use the Arduino directly but i have no more pins to use so i thought about this circuit, i am willing to use the attiny in sleep mode and wake it in Bouton press or analog change (BEMFA).

Comment: What about IRFL9014 ?

Comment: @GellyHamb it's really offtopic here to ask for exact parts, but for your needs you would like to look for "logic level" MOSFETs with enough current capabilities. One of the P-ch easily available (usually, depends on) parts are something like IRLML6402. It has lower gate threshold voltage, good current capabilities and still low gate charge for direct control from MCU. Rest depends on too much things...

Comment: Thanks for the reply and suggestion. Really appreciate it.